# Bash condition with AND OR operators

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, operators, sh

I've got a bash shell that gets options as either month (mm) and year (yyyy) or time (mmyyyy).
I can parse options and assign them to variables. Now, I need some conditions to check for those variables. What I need is: if (month AND year) OR time then proceed else display usage. This is my code and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
if [[ -z $MONTH && -z $YEAR ]] || [[ -z $TIME ]]; then
    usage
    exit 1
else
    if [[ -z $TIME ]]; then
        echo $MONTH$YEAR
    else
        echo $TIME
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is a bit backward. This:

```
if [[ -z $MONTH && -z $YEAR ]] || [[ -z $TIME ]]; then
    usage
```

("if I'm missing both month and year, it's an error; or, if I have those, but am missing time, it's an error") should be this:

```
if [[ -z $MONTH || -z $YEAR ]] && [[ -z $TIME ]]; then
    usage
```

("if I'm missing month or year, *and* I'm missing time, it's an error").